# HERE maps for JavaScript API: How to get toll prices?

Tags: javascript, here-api

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2.1.0/heremaps/maps-api-for-javascript-examples/tree/master/truck-routing-road-restrictions)

If I clearly understand I can add

```
routeRequestParams = {
      legattributes:'sm,sc',
    }
```

And get `summaryByCountry` but without price. What parameters should I add to get toll road price?
Because here api can do this
[documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/calculation-considerations.html)

Comment: Hi, would you please share with us what is the use case for this question? So we can understand it and try to provide you with the best resolution on this.

Also, we highly suggest checking the next request using route API to fetch the toll costs.

https://demo.routing.ext.here.com/#url=https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apikey=DEFAULT_API_KEY&origin=52.537936,13.390746&destination=45.651179,23.009905&return=polyline,summary,actions,instructions,travelSummary,tolls&spans=length,truckAttributes&transportMode=car

Best regards, Isaac.